How to check for uncommited changes to git in a subset of files using python
I'm doing data analysis, and for reproducibility I want to make sure my results are marked with the version of the code used to produce them. I do this with
import git
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
last_commit_hex = repo.head.object.hexsha

But that's not necessarily the actual state of the code if there's uncommitted changes. So I want an automatic check in the program just before it starts running the analysis. I can use  repo.is_dirty() to check for uncommitted changes in the repo. But that's checking too much. Besides the core package, there's also a bunch of miscellaneous files. Testing, other analysis scripts that use that core package, etc. And those don't need to be fully committed, but will trigger is_dirty(). How do I only check for the relevant files?
So, if my file system looks like this:
Repo folder
|- package_folder
   |- __init__.py
   |- module1.py
   |- module2.py
   |- ...
|- some_analysis_script1.py
|- some_analysis_script2.py
|- some_testing.py
|- ...

I would want to check only the contents of package_folder. Getting the list of files can be done with os.listdir, but how do I check which ones have been changed?

Run git status --short with subprocess  and parse the output or try with pure python using pygit2 https://pypi.org/project/pygit2/0.16.2/

Using the git status command suggested by eftshift0, I've gotten the following solution:
def check_all_committed_git()->bool:
    out = subprocess.run([ "git", "status", "--porcelain", "-uno" ], shell=True, capture_output=True,
                   encoding='UTF-8').stdout

    responses = out.split('\n')
    responses = [stripped for s in responses if len(stripped:=s.strip())>0]

    split = {file:status for status, file in (response.split(' ', maxsplit=1) for response in responses)}

    all_commited = not any(s.startswith(package_folder) for s in split)

    return all_commited

where package_folder should be whatever the name of your package is.
